# Create and keep track of pop-up window inside of electron app

Tags: popup, electron, microsoft-teams

I am running code that is being run inside of an Electron app. I do not have control over the Electron app (it's Microsoft Teams).

Inside of my code, I'm trying to create a pop up window that does some authentication and then sends a message (via postMessage) to the opener that all is complete. (The opener will close the pop up and reload.)

I'm having a couple of issues:

1. From the pop-up window, window.opener is null. This prevents me from sending a message back to the parent window. I've seen this issue detailed in Electron issue threads, but the solutions are always for devs who have control over the Electron environment. I do not.
2. The pop up opens in a new full web page, not a pop up. I cannot control the width or height of the pop up window.

From a different bug (navigator.languages is an empty array), I can surmise that Microsoft Teams is running an older version of Electron (3.x). Not sure if that's a showstopper or not.

Comment: This is already supported as part of [Microsoft Teams SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/msteams-client?view=msteams-client-js-latest). Here is how you [Initiate authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-tab-aad#initiate-authentication-flow). Please let us know if you looking for something else.

Comment: Thanks - that's understood and being utilized. This case, however, is a unique situation where we need to trigger a pop up from within an iFrame within our Teams app.

I'm actively thinking about how to re-organize code so I can use the authenticate() call from the teams library.

Comment: Well, that's all there is, so hopefully you get it to work.